# DNS service not propagating after 48hrs of NS change

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, digital-ocean, amazon-route53

I have run into a very weird issue. I want to migrate my DNS service from DigitalOcean to AWS Route53. So, I created a hosted zone in Route53, created my A records and everything. Then I changed the NS records of DO with the entries of route53.

The output of dig command shows the updated NS records ,i.e NS records of route53. But, A name entry is served from DO.

I verified this by changing the A record in route53. It did not change the dig output. Then, I rolled back the change in route53 and made a A record change in DO. It immediately updated the dig output with new entry.

It has been more than 60 hours after the change in the NS records.

To summarize, my entries are like:

**Route53 entries**

NS records:
ns1.aws
ns2.aws

A :
x.y.z.232

SOA :
aws.SOA

**DO Entries**

NS records:
ns1.aws
ns2.aws

A :
x.y.z.240

SOA :
digitalocean.SOA

**Output of Dig**

NS:
ns1.aws
ns2.aws

SOA:
digitalocean.SOA

A:
x.y.z.240

What's wrong here ? What changes are needed ?

I want my A record to be served from route53.

Comment: You are asking for help to publish information, yet for some reason you have chosen to hide the information in question. By doing so, you have also effectively prevented those who might be able to tell you what's wrong from doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the the domain registrar is actually godaddy and not DO. Hence, I had to make changes to the NS records in godaddy to reflect the changes. Still, why https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/ was showing NS values changed in DO is beyond me